# Global orientation class of $M$ implies top homology is $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, manifolds, homology-cohomology, orientation

Let $M$ a compact, connected $m$-manifold. Assume that there exists a global orientation class, i.e. an $\sigma_M \in H_m(M;\mathbb{Z})$ such that for all $x\in M$ the element $(\rho_{x,M})_{\ast}(\sigma_M)$ is a generator of the local homology group $H_m(M,M\setminus x;\mathbb{Z})\cong \mathbb{Z}.$ Here $(\rho_{x,M})_{\ast}\colon H_m(M;\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow H_m(M,M\setminus x;\mathbb{Z})$ is the morphism induced by the map of pairs $\rho_{x,M}\colon (M,\emptyset)\rightarrow (M,M\setminus x)$. I want to prove that then $H_m(M;\mathbb{Z})\cong \mathbb{Z}.$

First, since no generator of $\mathbb{Z}$ has finite order and since applying a group homomorphism can not increase the order of an element, $\sigma_M$ has infinite order.

Now I want to prove that $\sigma_M$ is a generator of $H_m(M;\mathbb{Z})$. To see this, let $a\in H_m(M;\mathbb{Z})$. Then for all $x\in M$ there exists $k_{x,a}\in \mathbb{Z}$ with $(\rho_{x,M})_{\ast}(a)=k_{x,a}\cdot (\rho_{x,M})_{\ast}(\sigma_M)$, since $(\rho_{x,M})_{\ast}(\sigma_M)$ is a generator.

My notes now read as follows:

> As the $(\rho_{x,M})_{\ast}(\sigma_M)$ are all coherent, **these $k_{x,a}$ have to be constant, i.e. equal to some $k$,** and if we set $b:=a-k\sigma_M$, we see $(\rho_{x,M})_{\ast}(b)=0$ for all $x\in M$. Therefore $b=0$.

How does the sentence marked in bold follow from the fact that the local orientations $(\rho_{x,M})_{\ast}(\sigma_M)$ are all coherent? Put differently, why is $\sigma_M$ a generator?

---

Edit on the definitions used:

Let $M$ be an $m$-manifold.

- For $x\in M$, a choice of generator $\sigma_x\in H_m(M,M\setminus x)$ is called a *local orientation at x*.
- A family of local orientations $(\sigma_x)_{x\in M}$ is called *coherent* if for any $x\in M$ there exists an open neighbourhood $U_x$ of $x$ and an element $\sigma_{U_x}\in H_m(M,M\setminus U_x)$ such that $(\rho_{y,U_x})_{\ast}(\sigma_{U_x})=\sigma_y$ for all $y\in U_x$.
- An *orientation* on $M$ is a choice of a coherent family of local orientations.

Comment: Have you tried showing that $k_{x,a}$ is constant on charts?

Comment: Before seeing the answer below I was struggling a bit on what you were assuming and what you were trying to prove.  One standard approach is to DEFINE such a manifold to be orientable if the top homology group is $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Orientable or not, the local relative groups at each point $p$ are all isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ and then one should be able to prove that the top group being the integers implies that the induced maps consistently hit the same generator of the local groups.  I think you are assuming the top group is nonzero and trying to prove that it is the integers IF a given element hits all those at a common $k$, and it looks like the answer below fills in this (non-trivial) step.

Comment: Finally, where you state "my notes read...." - was this from a lecture or class and it's this key step you were trying to justify (which the answer below fills in)?

Comment: Can you state the definition of "coherence" in this situation?

Comment: @LeeMosher Done.

Comment: @AlgTop1854 I am assuming that there exists $\sigma_M\in H_m(M)$ such that under every restriction from $H_m(M)$ to a local homology group $\sigma_M$ is mapped to a generator. I am trying to show that this implies $H_m(M)\cong \mathbb{Z}$. This was from my lecture notes, yes. The answer below, if it is correct, answers my question.

Answer (score 1):

The proof strategy can be summarized as follows: First, we prove the claim for the charts of $M$. Then we transport along paths.

Let $x,y\in M$. Since $M$ is path-connected (any connected manifold is path-connected), there is a path $\gamma\colon [0,1]\rightarrow M$ from $x$ to $y$. For any $z\in \operatorname{im}(\gamma)$, find an open neighbourhood $z\in U_z\cong \mathring{\mathbb{D}}^m$. These $U_z$ form an open cover of the compact set $\operatorname{im}(\gamma)$. We choose a minimal finite subcover $\{U_1,\ldots,U_n\}$ consisting of $n$ elements, say. Next we prove $k_x=k_y$ by induction on the minimal size $n$ of a finite subcover.

Before doing so, I'll simplify notation for better legibility. Namely, set $\sigma_x:= (\rho_{x,M})_{\ast}(\sigma_M)$ and $\sigma_y:= (\rho_{y,M})_{\ast}(\sigma_M)$.

For the base case $n=1$, note that by functoriality of homology $$k_{x}\sigma_x=(\rho_{x,M})_{\ast}(a)= (\rho_{x,U_1})_{\ast}\circ  (\rho_{U_1,M})_{\ast}(a)$$ $$k_{y}\sigma_y=(\rho_{y,U_1})_{\ast}\circ  (\rho_{U_1,M})_{\ast}(a).$$ Additionally, observe that by excision both $(\rho_{x,U_1})_{\ast}$ and $(\rho_{y,U_1})_{\ast}$ are isomorphisms. Thus, we find $$k_x\cdot (\rho_{x,U_1})_{\ast}^{-1}(\sigma_x)=(\rho_{x,U_1})_{\ast}^{-1}(k_{x}\sigma_x)= (\rho_{y,U_1})_{\ast}^{-1}(k_{y}\sigma_y)= k_y\cdot (\rho_{y,U_1})_{\ast}^{-1}(\sigma_y).$$
Again by functoriality of homology, we have $(\rho_{x,U_1})_{\ast}^{-1}(\sigma_x)= (\rho_{U_1,M})_{\ast}(\sigma_M)= (\rho_{y,U_1})_{\ast}^{-1}(\sigma_y).$ Moreover, since $\sigma_x$ is a generator of $H_m(M,M\setminus x;\mathbb{Z})\cong \mathbb{Z}$ and $(\rho_{x,U_1})_{\ast}$ is an isomorphism, we know that also $(\rho_{x,U_1})_{\ast}^{-1}(\sigma_x)=(\rho_{y,U_1})_{\ast}^{-1}(\sigma_y)$ is a generator of $H_m(M,M\setminus U_1;\mathbb{Z})\cong \mathbb{Z}$. Thus $k_x=k_y$.

Next, assume that the claim is proven for all pairs of points which posses a path between them whose image can be covered by $n-1\geq 1$ open neighbourhoods of the above form. I'll give a kind of parallel transport argument. Let $x,y\in M$ be points with the property that no path between them can be covered by $n-1$ open neighbourhoods of the above form, but for which a path exists which can be covered by $n$ open neighbourhoods of the above form. Pick such a path $\gamma$ and such a minimal open cover $\{U_1,\ldots,U_n\}$ of size $n$. Since the image of $\gamma$ is connected and since $n$ is minimal, there exists $j\neq 1$ such that $U_1\cap U_j$ is non-empty. Pick such a $j$. Similarly, if $n\neq 2$, there exists $i\neq 1$ such that $U_i\cap(U_1\cup U_j)$ is non-empty. We can repeat this procedure and find an order $U_1,U_j,U_i,\ldots$ on the $U_l$'s in the open cover such that each $U_l$ intersects the union of all its predecessors. Without loss of generality assume that the order found is given by the order of the indices, i.e. $j=2$, $i=3$, and so on. Next, note that $\bigcup_{l\leq n-1}U_l$ is path-connected: $U_1\cup U_2$ is a union of two path-connected sets with non-empty intersection, thus it is path connected. Analogously, $(U_1\cup U_2)\cup U_3$ is the union of two path-connected sets with non-empty intersection. And so on (secretly this is an induction proof) …
Thus, we can apply the induction hypothesis, and find that $k_{z_1}=k_{z_2}$ for any $z_1,z_2\in\bigcup_{l\leq n-1}U_l$. But $U_n\cap \bigcup_{i\leq n-1}U_i$ is non-empty and $k_x=k_y$ follows.

Comment: Can't you just argue that $\{x\in M: k_x=k\}$ and $\{x\in M:k_x\neq k\}$ are both open, since $k_x$ is locally constant and conclude that one has to be empty, since $M$ is connected?

Comment: @VincentBoelens Oh, yes! That is of course way more elegant. I'll add your argument to my answer with mention of your name, if you do not mind? Otherwise you could of course also write an own answer.

Comment: No need to credit, just add it into your answer so that it looks cleaner.