# Top homology $\mathbb{Z}$ implies orientability

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, manifolds, homology-cohomology, orientation

Let $M$ a compact, connected $m$-manifold. Assume that $H_m(M;\mathbb{Z})\cong \mathbb{Z}.$ I want to show that then $M$ is orientable.

My ideas:

Let $o_M$ one of the two generators of $H_m(M;\mathbb{Z})\cong \mathbb{Z}.$ If I could show that for any $x\in M$ the restriction map $(\rho_{x,M})_{\ast}\colon H_m(M;\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow H_m(M,M\setminus x;\mathbb{Z})$ is an isomorphism I would be done, since then $((\rho_{x,M})_{\ast}(o_M) \vert x\in M)$ would be a family of coherent generators. I convinced myself that $(\rho_{x,M})_{\ast}\colon H_m(M;\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow H_m(M,M\setminus x;\mathbb{Z})$ is injective for any $x\in M$ using the LES and Poincaré duality. But why is each restriction surjective? Can't it be multiplication by some $n\neq 0,1,-1$? If so it would have to be multiplication by the same $n$ for all $x$ by the argument given in the answer to my question [Global orientation class of $M$ implies top homology is $\mathbb{Z}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4780895/global-orientation-class-of-m-implies-top-homology-is-mathbbz). But why can't that be?

My notes argue like that:

> For surjectivity consider $(\rho_{x,M})_{\ast}o_M)\vert x\in M)=(k_xo_x)\vert x\in M )$ for some collection $k_x$. But $k_x$ is locally constant on $M$ and thus constant, and if there is a coherent choice $(ko_x\vert x\in M)$ it follows that $(o_x \vert x\in M)$ is a coherent choice of orientation.

I included the typos, maybe how I am fixing them in my head is not how they should be fixed. Anyway, I do not understand that passage.

---

*EDIT:*

- Mikhail Katz claims in the comments that my question is equivalent to asking why the map $H_m(S_m)\rightarrow H_m(S^m,S^m\setminus x)$ is surjective. Why is that equivalent to my question?
- I would also be happy with a reference.

Comment: By excision, this is equivalent to asking why the map $H_m(S^m)\to H_m(S^m,S^m\setminus x)$ is onto, which should be a basic calculation in every algebraic topology textbook.

Comment: @MikhailKatz Thanks. I can show that $H_m(S^m)\rightarrow H_m(S^m,S^m\setminus x)$ is an iso using the LES and that $S^m\setminus x$ is contractible. But how do I apply excision to get there? What space am I excising?

Comment: If $B$ is a small ball around $x\in M$, then $H_m(M,M\setminus x)$ should be isomorphic to $H_m(B, B\setminus x)$.

Comment: @MikhailKatz And this in turn should be isomorphic to $\tilde{H}_{m-1}(B\setminus x)\cong \tilde{H}_{m-1}(S^{m-1})$. But how does that help? I am struggling to see how this relates to $H_m(M)$?

Comment: Before we apply the next isomorphism in the long exact sequence, do you agree with the isomorphism $H_m(M,M∖x)\simeq H_m(B,B∖x)$?

Comment: @MikhailKatz Yes.

Comment: Good, at this point one should be able to write down a commutative diagram to get what you want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148956/discussion-between-margaret-and-mikhail-katz).

Comment: What kind of homology are you dealing with here? There's a general approach to orientation with sheaf (co)homology that has a corresponding version of Poincare duality, but the ad hoc approach in something like Hatcher that still stays in singular/cellular/etc. homology is also common.

Comment: @anomaly Singular homology.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using Poincare duality already, I think it is fair to quote the following theorem that is usually stated in preparation for Poincare duality:

(Orientation Theorem): Let $M$ be compact manifold. Then the map

$ j : H_n(M;R) \to \Gamma(M, \omicron_M \otimes R) $

is an isomorphism, the latter $R$ module referring to the set of sections of the covering map $p: \omicron_M \otimes R \to M$ [look  for example from Haynes Miller lecture notes in AT: 31.13 https://math.mit.edu/~hrm/papers/lectures-905-906.pdf].

Also, consider the following composite map

$\tau:  \omicron_M = \bigsqcup_{x \in M} H_n(M|x) \to^{\sqcup_x \overline{\phi}_x} \bigsqcup_{x \in M} \mathbb{Z}/\{ \pm 1\}  \to \mathbb{Z}/\{ \pm 1\}  $

where $\overline{\phi}_x$ is the composite $H_n(M|x) \to^{\cong} \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/\{ \pm 1\} $. $\tau$ is continuous with respect to the topology on $\omicron_M$ defined as e.g. the above lecture notes.

With this in mind:

By your assumption and the above theorem, $ \Gamma(M, \omicron_M \otimes \mathbb{Z}) \cong H_n(M; \mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}$. Hence there is a non zero section, i.e. a continuous map $s: M \to \omicron_M \otimes \mathbb{Z}$. As it is non zero, $\exists x_0 \in M, k \in \mathbb{Z}\setminus \{ 0 \} :  s(x_0) \in \tau^{-1}(\{ \pm k \})$.

As composite $\tau \circ s: M \to \mathbb{Z}/\{\pm 1\}$ is continuous, but since $M$ is connected and $\mathbb{Z}/\{ \pm 1\}$ is discrete, it must be constant. Hence $\forall x \in M : s(x) \in \tau^{-1}(\{ \pm k \})$, and $s: M \to \tau^{-1}(\{ \pm k \} ) $. One can see that

$ f: (\omicron_M \otimes \mathbb{Z})^{\times} = \tau^{-1}(\{ \pm 1\}) \to \tau^{-1}(\{ \pm k \}), \alpha \mapsto k \cdot \alpha $

is a homeomorphism and since it preserves the fibres, an isomorphism of the two fibre bundles. Thus the composite $f^{-1}\circ s : M \to \omicron_M$ is a section, showing that $M$ is orientable.

If you find mistakes in the argumentation let me know, I am also just now learning this subject.

**EDIT**

You can consider the commutative diagram of $R$ modules, for arbitrary $x \in M$:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
H_n(M) @>{j_{\emptyset, x}}>> H_n(M, M\setminus x)\\
@V{j}VV @A{ev_x}AA \\
\Gamma(M, \omicron_M) @>{id}>> \Gamma(M, \omicron_M)
\end{CD}
where $j$ is defined as

$\forall \alpha \in H_n(M): \quad j(\alpha) : M \to \omicron_M, x \mapsto j(\alpha)(x) = j_{\emptyset, x}(\alpha) $.

One can check that $j(\alpha)$ is continuous and is therefore well defined. The evaluation map evaluates a given section at a point $x \in M$.

Now if you take it as a fact that the top map $j_{\emptyset, x}$ is injective, it follows that $j$ must also be injective (btw, the map $ev_x$ is also injective, stemming from the fact that $M$ is connected). In particular there is a non-zero section in $\Gamma(M, \omicron_M)$, since by assumption $H_n(M) \neq 0 $. Given this non-zero section, you can again apply the proof above, without referring to the Orientation Theorem.

If you find something even more elementary let me know.

Comment: Isn't there a more elementary way to prove this? I havent seen this theorem before.

Comment: look at the edit, I would not consider that elementary as you use poincare duality, but it incorporates your results.

Comment: Does it follow that if $(\rho_{x,M})_{\ast}\colon H_m(M;\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow H_m(M,M\setminus x;\mathbb{Z})$ if an isomorphism for all $x$ that is has to be the *same* isomorphism (i.e. hit $1$ or $-1$ for all $x$?). It feels like it should, and if it could hit both as $x$ varies then $M$ would not be orientable, but that can't be right because then the top homology would vanish so no isomorphisms at all.

Comment: if $\rho_*$ is an isomorphism, and you take a generator $\alpha$ in $H_n(M)$, then $\rho_*(\alpha) \in H_n(M|x)$ will be a generator as well. This suffices the definition of orient ability, that you use, as $M$ is an open neighbourhood of any $x \in M$. Note that there is no canonical isomorphism $H_n(M ,M\setminus x) \to \mathbb{Z}$, as you can also compose it with the isomorphism $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}, z \mapsto -z$. Hence you cannot talk about the "same" isomorphism.

Comment: that is also why in my answer above, $\phi : H_n(M|x) \to \mathbb{Z}$ is not canonical, and you have to $\it{choose}$ one such isomorphism, but the composition $\overline{\phi} : H_n(M|x) \to \mathbb{Z}/ \{ \pm 1 \} $ $\it{is}$ canonical.